# How to load a PostgreSQL sample database using pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm a beginner and I'm currently following this tutorial on how to load a PostgreSQL sample satabase: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/

I have downloaded the sample database and in the link it says "navigate the BIN folder of the PostgreSQL installation folder:" followed by this line of code:

```
C:\>cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin
```

But I have no clue where to put this code. I went to Tools > Query Tool and tried to put in that code (with some adjustments; I changed it to the location of BIN folder in my computer) but when I clicked on execute query, it gave me this message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "C"
LINE 1: C:\>cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin
        ^
```

I don't where I went wrong. How to solve this problem?

Comment: It's right there: "*Third, use the pg_restore tool to load data into the dvdrental database:*" including an example command line

Answer (score 0):

That's a command-line script, to be run from the cmd.exe shell (Windows "Command Prompt"). It's not SQL you can run from within PgAdmin.

If the database is a backup from `pg_dump -Fc` you can use PgAdmin to restore it instead of `pg_restore` on the command line. See http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.16/restore.html